# compare two different size array ( component of A is in B )

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What I want to do is there are two different size array
Let

```
A = [[1,3,1],[2,4,1],[3,3,1]]
B = [[1,3,1],[2,5,1],[2,3,1],[3,3,1],[5,5,1]]
```

Row of B may in A or not`( [1,3,1], [3,3,1] is in A )`

What I want to do from these arrays is compare two arrays in order to construct 
array "C" which is consist of the rows of B that is in A

```
C = [[1,3,1], [3,3,1]]
```

I have tried pandas.isin but I have failed.. Any idea would be very helpful

Comment: in short, you want common elements from both lists.. correct??

Comment: If you treat the arrays as sets, this is intersection.

Comment: oh, yes.. that is common elements

Answer (score 2):

Use `set.intersection`

**Ex:**

```
A = [[1,3,1],[2,4,1],[3,3,1]]
B = [[1,3,1],[2,5,1],[2,3,1],[3,3,1],[5,5,1]]

A = map(tuple, A)
B = map(tuple, B)
print(set(A).intersection(set(B)))
```

**Output:**

```
{(3, 3, 1), (1, 3, 1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get common elements from both lists:

```
>>> A = [[1,3,1],[2,4,1],[3,3,1]]
>>> B = [[1,3,1],[2,5,1],[2,3,1],[3,3,1],[5,5,1]]
>>> print([data for data in A if data in B])
[[1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I got hind from eariler comments from others, and this is it!

Comment: You can remove the `if data in A`, since it is already `for data in A`.

Comment: @Keldorn : Yeah..true that.. no need to add `if data in A` as I am looping on `A` only.. Modified answer..

Answer (score 0):

Or with `filter`:

```
print(list(filter(lambda x: x in A.tolist(), B.tolist())))
```

Output:

```
[[1, 3, 1], [3, 3, 1]]
```